# Spring Boot Kafka with MANUAL_IMMEDIATE ack

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Springboot app. wiuth this configuration:

```
  kafka:
    consumer:
      listener:
        ack-mode: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

ad this consumer:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {
            ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

but I have this error when receiving a message:

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment] for GenericMessage
```

Comment: Remove the `consumer` element. Your IDE should help you with property validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your YAML is not being read; I just tested it

**CORRECTION**

You have invalid YAML - remove the `consumer` element.

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    listener:
      ack-mode: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
```

And it worked fine; removing the `ack-mode` gives me the same error that you see.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60929385Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60929385Application.class, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60929385", topics = "so60929385")
    public void listen(String in, Acknowledgment ack) {
        System.out.println(in);
        ack.acknowledge();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> template.send("so60929385", "foo");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so60929385").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this error when starting  Consumer cannot be configured for auto commit for ackMode MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Comment: You must be using an old version. Set `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit: false` - it has been `false` by default since version 2.3 (which is the version used by Spring Boot 2.2).